# Как из списка-словаря достать конкретное значение по заданному параметру

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, словари

парсятся данные о валютах с сайта ЦБ и помещаются в список-словарь valute.
И чтобы оттуда достать например курс доллара нужно указать valute[10]['rate'].
Как можно сделать так, циклом например, чтобы человек вводил название валюты 'USD' и на основании этого уже выводился бы курс.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'accept': '*/*',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'http://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/'


def converter(url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    valute = []
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        line = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'data'}).findAll('tr')
        for tr in line:
            td = tr.findAll('td')
            if not td:
                continue
            numcode = td[0].text
            litcode = td[1].text
            num = td[2].text
            val = td[3].text
            rate = td[4].text

            valute.append({
                'numCode': numcode,
                'litCode': litcode,
                'num': num,
                'val': val,
                'rate': rate
            })
        print(valute[10]['rate'])
    else:
        print('Error')


converter(url, headers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На выход вы получаете список в переменную valute,  в которой содержаться словари с курсами.

```
[{'numCode': '036', 'litCode': 'AUD', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Австралийский доллар', 'rate': '43,7383'}, {'numCode': '944', 'litCode': 'AZN', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Азербайджанский манат', 'rate': '37,6977'}, {'numCode': '051', 'litCode': 'AMD', 'num': '100', 'val': 'Армянских драмов', 'rate': '13,4329'}, {'numCode': '933', 'litCode': 'BYN', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Белорусский рубль', 'rate': '31,3778'}, {'numCode': '975', 'litCode': 'BGN', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Болгарский лев', 'rate': '36,3914'}, {'numCode': '986', 'litCode': 'BRL', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Бразильский реал', 'rate': '15,3640'}, {'numCode': '348', 'litCode': 'HUF', 'num': '100', 'val': 'Венгерских форинтов', 'rate': '21,5026'}, {'numCode': '410', 'litCode': 'KRW', 'num': '1000', 'val': 'Вон Республики Корея', 'rate': '54,1471'}, {'numCode': '344', 'litCode': 'HKD', 'num': '10', 'val': 'Гонконгских долларов', 'rate': '81,5430'}, {'numCode': '208', 'litCode': 'DKK', 'num': '10', 'val': 'Датских крон', 'rate': '95,2791'}, {'numCode': '840', 'litCode': 'USD', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Доллар США', 'rate': '63,9542'}, {'numCode': '978', 'litCode': 'EUR', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Евро', 'rate': '71,1299'}, {'numCode': '356', 'litCode': 'INR', 'num': '100', 'val': 'Индийских рупий', 'rate': '89,9225'}, {'numCode': '398', 'litCode': 'KZT', 'num': '100', 'val': 'Казахстанских тенге', 'rate': '16,3922'}, {'numCode': '124', 'litCode': 'CAD', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Канадский доллар', 'rate': '48,6862'}, {'numCode': '417', 'litCode': 'KGS', 'num': '100', 'val': 'Киргизских сомов', 'rate': '91,3775'}, {'numCode': '156', 'litCode': 'CNY', 'num': '10', 'val': 'Китайских юаней', 'rate': '90,2938'}, {'numCode': '498', 'litCode': 'MDL', 'num': '10', 'val': 'Молдавских леев', 'rate': '36,8188'}, {'numCode': '934', 'litCode': 'TMT', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Новый туркменский манат', 'rate': '18,2988'}, {'numCode': '578', 'litCode': 'NOK', 'num': '10', 'val': 'Норвежских крон', 'rate': '69,5555'}, {'numCode': '985', 'litCode': 'PLN', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Польский злотый', 'rate': '16,6214'}, {'numCode': '946', 'litCode': 'RON', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Румынский лей', 'rate': '14,9681'}, {'numCode': '960', 'litCode': 'XDR', 'num': '1', 'val': 'СДР (специальные права заимствования)', 'rate': '88,0087'}, {'numCode': '702', 'litCode': 'SGD', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Сингапурский доллар', 'rate': '46,8460'}, {'numCode': '972', 'litCode': 'TJS', 'num': '10', 'val': 'Таджикских сомони', 'rate': '66,0002'}, {'numCode': '949', 'litCode': 'TRY', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Турецкая лира', 'rate': '11,0588'}, {'numCode': '860', 'litCode': 'UZS', 'num': '10000', 'val': 'Узбекских сумов', 'rate': '67,8199'}, {'numCode': '980', 'litCode': 'UAH', 'num': '10', 'val': 'Украинских гривен', 'rate': '25,5724'}, {'numCode': '826', 'litCode': 'GBP', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства', 'rate': '82,5073'}, {'numCode': '203', 'litCode': 'CZK', 'num': '10', 'val': 'Чешских крон', 'rate': '27,7230'}, {'numCode': '752', 'litCode': 'SEK', 'num': '10', 'val': 'Шведских крон', 'rate': '65,9852'}, {'numCode': '756', 'litCode': 'CHF', 'num': '1', 'val': 'Швейцарский франк', 'rate': '64,7966'}, {'numCode': '710', 'litCode': 'ZAR', 'num': '10', 'val': 'Южноафриканских рэндов', 'rate': '43,2591'}, {'numCode': '392', 'litCode': 'JPY', 'num': '100', 'val': 'Японских иен', 'rate': '58,8626'}]
```

Вы можете назначить через if-elif-else для каждого обозначения валюты свой номер, или сделать для этого словарь и, когда пользователь будет вводить название валюты (тот же USD), программа будет вводить вместо X в команде

```
valute[X]['rate']
```

номер этой валюты (т.е. 10)

===========================================================================

```
inputed = input('Введите код валюты')

    for val in valute:
        if inputed in val['litCode']:
            valute_index = valute.index(val)
            break
```

в valute_index будет храниться индекс словаря, в котором присутствует та самая валюта, т.е. будет в итоге `valute[valute_index]['rate']`

Comment: Да, спасибо, можно так попробовать, но а если бы этот порядок на сайте менялся как нибудь?
Я так понимаю каждый словарь - это же один элемент списка?
Можно ли как то прописать, чтобы поиск велся внутри ключа словаря 'litCode' и если он равен например 'USD', то оставить только этот словарь?

Comment: Изменил ответ, вроде понял, что вы хотели

Comment: Спасибо, да, это то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Создайте вместо списка словарь.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'accept': '*/*',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'http://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/'


def converter(url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(url, headers=headers)

#    valute = []
    valute = {}                                                        # +++

    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        line = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'data'}).findAll('tr')
        for tr in line:
            td = tr.findAll('td')
            if not td:
                continue
            numcode = td[0].text
            litcode = td[1].text
            num = td[2].text
            val = td[3].text
            rate = td[4].text

            valute[litcode] = rate                                       # +++

    while True:
        litcode = input("Введите Букв. код ваюты (выход Enter): ").upper()
        if not litcode:
            break

        rate = valute.get(litcode)
        if rate:
            print("{}: {}\n".format(litcode, valute[litcode])) 
        else:
            print('Error: неверный код ваюты')

converter(url, headers)
```

---

```
Введите Букв. код ваюты (выход Enter): usd
USD: 63,9542
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде всё робит)

Comment: @Try Fly пожалуйста :)